# Two Sample test of proportions with dependent trials

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, multinomial-distribution, independence

I have data $$X_1,\ldots,X_T \qquad Y_1,\ldots,Y_T$$ where $X_i \sim \text{Categorical}(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ and $Y_i \sim \text{Categorical}(b_1,\ldots,b_k)$, but the $X_i$ are not independent of one another (neither are $Y_i$). The $X_i$ ARE independent of $Y_i$ though.

I want to test whether $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)=(b_1,\ldots,b_k)$. Now if the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ were indepdnent then I would simply do Pearson Chi-square Test. What options do I have? What would you do?

Comment: What data are they? Can you be more specific with an example, if there is one? What caused the dependence? Is it due to MCMC or time series?

Comment: dependence is due to the fact that the data come from MCMC (which you can view as a time series).

Comment: What about adjusting the rows (X) and columns (Y) of the table by the effective sample size of X and the effective sample size of Y?

Comment: thats actually what I ended up doing!

Comment: Ha! Is that the correct way to do it? How did you get the effective sample sizes? By fitting AR(p)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually ended up writing a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04919) to answer this question. One of the approaches in the paper is similar to what @JunchiGuo suggested in the comments (adjusting by effective sample size) where the ESS was calculated assuming the data follow an NDARMA model.